# What is wrong with my RelayCommand? Data loads on button press but won't load on page appearing 

Tags: c#, .net, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I'm learning C# and .NET Maui, and have run into another problem that I can't wrap my head around.

I have some data loading in from a website api, but I can only seem to get it to load into a ListView after pressing a button and can't get it to do so on loading the page.  I'm hoping someone can see my problem and point me in the right direction.

First, here is the relevant part of my ViewModel.:

```
    public ICommand LoadPostsCommand { get; set; }

    public PostsViewModel() 
    {
        LoadPostsCommand = new Command(async () => await LoadPosts());
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    void Appearing()
    {
        LoadPostsCommand = new Command(async () => await LoadPosts());
    }
```

here is my code behind:

```
using App.ViewModels;

namespace App.Views;
public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
{
    public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new PostsViewModel();
    }
}
```

and my page xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App.Views.HomePage" Title="Posts"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:App.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="vm:PostsViewModel"
             xmlns:mct="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Maui.Behaviors;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Maui"
             >
    <ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <mct:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding AppearingCommand}" EventName="Appearing" />
        <mct:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding DisappearingCommand}" EventName="Disappearing" />
    </ContentPage.Behaviors>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Posts}" SeparatorVisibility="None">
        <ListView.Header>
            <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

                <Button 
                    x:Name="UpdateBtn"
                    Text="Load Posts"
                    Command="{Binding LoadPostsCommand}"
                    Margin="10"
                    />

            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </ListView.Header>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid Padding="10">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.RowSpan="2"
                           Source="{Binding Image.ImageUrl}"
                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                           HeightRequest="60"
                           WidthRequest="60" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1"
                           Text="{Binding Title}"
                           FontAttributes="Bold" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="1"
                           Grid.Column="1"
                           Text="{Binding Body}"                          
                           FontAttributes="None"
                           Margin="5"
                           VerticalOptions="End" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="2"
                           Grid.Column="1"
                           Text="{Binding Username}"                         
                           FontAttributes="None"
                           Margin="5"
                           VerticalOptions="End" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

When I press the button, the content loads into the ListView - but it doesn't load into the page on appearing. What am I missing here?  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need an `Appearing` command, you just need the page to call the `LoadPosts` method in it's `OnAppearing`

```
PostsViewModel vm;

public HomePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = vm = new PostsViewModel();
}

public async override void OnAppearing()
{
    await vm.LoadPosts();
}
```

Comment: Okay cool. I played around with OnAppearing() for a long while before stumbling upon some examples using [RelayCommand] - but couldn't ever get it to work.  

So, when I try it this way, I'm getting these errors:  

1. `'HomePage.OnAppearing()': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'Page.OnAppearing()'`

2. `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'PostsViewModel.LoadPosts()'`

Comment: try `protected` instead of `public`.  And look at the code I posted where I created a reference `vm` to the VM instance

Comment: Thank you! I totally missed the PostsViewModel vm; line so was getting errors with that too, lol - now I just need to think all of this over until I understand why this works.  You're the best!!